# android studio 3.1.1 editing build.gradle file slow

Tags: android, android-studio

I have update Android Studio to latest version 3.1.1, but is so slowly , especially when I editing build.gradle file , is there any solution ?
(before I use 3.0.1 , that is so fast)

Comment: The fastest solution is downgrade the version to an stable version.

Comment: @Antonio - 3.1.1 is the latest stable version.

Comment: 3.1.1 build is so slow, 3.1 is fast

Comment: Well , now Android Studio 3.1.2 has fixed this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this is only happening in China. Try this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47342580/501175

According to the answer above, there are two ways you can try:

1. You need to modify the proxy setting of your Android Studio
2. Simple add a line `127.0.0.1 search.maven.org` to the /etc/hosts file. I am using the second one and it works fine.

Comment: Same thing here in Russia.

And why is it blocking the editor's UI thread?

adding 127.0.0.1 for search.maven.org to /etc/hosts -> worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Got no idea :( maybe the android studio is sending network request on the UI thread, which is really not `android style`

Answer (score 1):

Well , now Android Studio 3.1.2 has fixed this problem

Comment: this actually was fixed and confirmed

Answer (score 0):

How's about downgrading Android Studio to 3.0.1? I had the same issue as you. As a result, I downgraded it.

In case anyone wants to download different versions of Android Studio, this is the link you need: [Download Archives](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's a reported bug in Android Studio you can follow the issue here
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77211316

It's been fixed in version 3.2 canary 11

Edit: They've released this fix with 3.1.2 in stable branch too.

Comment: At least you could commented why you down voted this?